# Is possible to open a file in the client from a web page?

Tags: sharepoint, activex, client-side, silverlight-5.0

I know, this is a stupid questiom but, my customer is stupid two.

I need to provide a link in sharepoint web page to open Microsoft Outlook and other link to open an .exe file (the SAP client).

Is there any magic way to do this? Silverlight, ActiveX, JS, Applets, etc, any idea are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the browser to open an external program by one of two methods:
1. Linking to a special URL, that is set to be handled by an external program
2. Linking to a URL with an extension registered to be opened by an external program.

Most notable example of #1 is the 'mailto' protocol. For example mailto:someone@somewhere.com will open the default mail program, in editing mode to the recipient. Another notable example is the 'itms' protocol, which will open iTunes (try: itms://url.in.apple.com).

You can also point to a resource with a registered example. For example, a URL ends with *.torrent will open uTorrent or whatever torrent handler you have on your machine (for example: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/ubuntu-12.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent will download Ubuntu from canonical web site).

I'm not familiar with SAP. If there is any canonical file extension for SAP clients - then you can have a resource on your web site. To open outlook, you can use the mailto protocol.

On a completely different route, you can of course implement (and then ... deploy) an ActiveX, which can do anything, including create whatever processes you want.

Comment: your anwswer covers important cenarios, in fact never touched my mind to use any SAP protocols. Actually, i am using the ActiveX approach using javascript (ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")) like described in my blog (http://ewer.com.br/abrir_arquivo_client_com_activex/). Thanks